# Plot behavior of values in a graph

Tags: matlab, graph

I have a file in the following format with a set of floating-point values:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
---end-of-run-1
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
a3 b3 c3
a4 b4 c4
a5 b5 c5 
---end-of-run-2
...
...
...
till n runs
```

I want to show this set of columns (i.e. comprising of a,b,c) as different curves on a graph. Also, number of values collected for each run will vary.

Which in-built functions can I use in matlab to determine the behavior of this set of values(a, b, c) over some `n runs` in a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but I would go line by line through the file.

```
function out = read_and_plot

fid = fopen('input.txt');

line_value = fgetl(fid);
i = 0;
while ischar(line_value)
     if strncmp('--end-of',line_value,8) % we need to start on the next run
        figure;
        plot_data = [col1' col2' col3'];
        plot(1:i', plot_data);
        legend('col1', 'col2', 'col3');
        % clear and restart
        i = 0;
        col1 = []; col2 = []; col3 = [];
     else % we have a line of data
        i = i + 1;
        data = sscanf(line_value, '%f %f %f');
        [col1(i),col2(i),col3(i)] = deal(data(1), data(2), data(3));
     end
     line_value = fgetl(fid);
end

fclose(fid);

return
```

Now, in order to determine the behavior of the values it would depend if you trying to curve fit or fit a distribution, if so I would recommend the curve fitting toolbox.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this script. How can I bring about this change: You are currently plotting the graph after each run, but I would like to collect the data over different runs, and then plot a single graph? (So there will be a 2-dimensional matrix for each column of my file, and the column number of the matrix will signify the run number). Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Sure, you would just add dimensions to plot_data. so where plot_data is now, global_plot_data = [global_plot_data; plot_data]; you would have to define global_plot_data = [] at the beginning, but could use the same plot command at the end.